# How can I create users server side in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

In the new Meteor auth branch how can I create users server side?

I see how to create them client side with the call to

```
[Client] Meteor.createUser(options, extra, callback)
```

But suppose I want to create a Meteor user collection record on startup?

For example, the Administrator account during startup/bootstrapping for an application?

Thanks
Steeve

Comment: you should update your accepted answer to one that says to use accounts.createuser

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably it's a well known fact now, but for the sake of completing this - there's a new server API for doing this on the `auth` branch. From the [docs on auth](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Auth):

> " [Server] Meteor.createUser(options, extra) - Creates a user and
>   sends that user an email with a link to choose their initial password
>   and complete their account enrollment
>
> options a hash containing: email (mandatory), username (optional)
>   extra: extra fields for the user object (eg name, etc). "

Please note the API is subject to change as it's not on the master branch yet.

Comment: Meteor now supports using 'createUser' on the server.  
Details here: http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_createuser

Answer (score 22):

**On newer versions of meteor use**

```
  Accounts.createUser({
                            username: username,
                            email : email,
                            password : password,
                            profile  : {
                                //publicly visible fields like firstname goes here
                            }

    });
```

**note**: the password hash is generated automatically

**On older versions of meteor use:**

1 - NB: DO YOU HAVE THE REQUIRED **PACKAGES** INSTALLED ?

- mrt add accounts-base
- mrt add accounts-password

On some versions of meteor you cannot call SRP password salt generator as Steeve suggested, so try this:

2 - do Meteor.users.insert( )

e.g.

```
 var newUserId = 
 Meteor.users.insert({
         emails: ['peter@jones.com'],
         profile  : { fullname : 'peter' }
 });
```

**note**: a user must have EITHER a username or an email address. I used email in this example.

3 - Finally set the password for the newly created account.

```
      Accounts.setPassword(newUserId, 'newPassword');
```

Comment: +1 For mentioning accounts-password. I was trying to use Accounts.createUser without this package, and it would not work!

Answer (score 8):

For now this has been suggested in the meteor-core google group.

```
Meteor.users.insert({username: 'foo', emails: ['bar@example.com'], name: 'baz', services:     {password: {srp: Meteor._srp.generateVerifier('password')}}});
```

It works.  I tested it in during startup/boot strap.

I would not consider this the permanent or long term answer because I believe the auth branch is still in a great degree of change and I imagine the team behind Meteor will provide some kind of functionality for it.

So, do not depend on this as a long term answer.

Steeve

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, I believe you cannot. Running

```
Meteor.call('createUser', {username: "foo", password: "bar"});
```

comes close, but the implementation of `createUser` in `passwords_server.js` calls `this.setUserId` on success, and `setUserId` cannot be called on the server unless we're in a client-initiated method invocation (search for "Can't call setUserId on a server initiated method call" in `livedata_server.js`.

This does seem like something worth supporting. Perhaps the last three lines of `createUser`, which log the user in, should be controlled by a new boolean `login` option to the method? Then you could use

```
Meteor.call('createUser', {username: "foo", password: "bar", login: false});
```

in server bootstrap code.

Answer (score 1):

I've confirmed that the following code in my server/seeds.js file works with the most recent version of Meteor (Release 0.8.1.1)

```
if (Meteor.users.find().count() === 0) {
  seedUserId = Accounts.createUser({
    email: 'f@oo.com',
    password: '123456'
  });
}
```

Directory (or folder) of `server` means I'm running the code on the server. The filename `seeds.js` is completely arbitrary.

The [official documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_createuser) now describes both the behavior for `Accounts.createUser()` when run on the client and when run on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Working coffeescript example for Meteor version 1.1.0.2 (server side):

```
userId = Accounts.createUser  
    username: 'user'
    email: 'user@company.com'
    password: 'password'
    profile:
      name: 'user name' 
user = Meteor.users.findOne userId
```

I struggled for some time with this API getting 'User already exists' exception in working code before adding profiles.name to the `options` and exception disappeared.

reference: [Accounts.createUser(options,[callback])](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser)

Answer (score 0):

Create user from server side

```
    // Server method
    Meteor.methods({
      register: function(data) {
       try {
         console.log("Register User");
         console.log(data);
         user = Accounts.createUser({
           username: data.email,
           email: data.email,
           password: data.password,
           profile: {
             name: data.email,
             createdOn: new Date(),
             IsInternal: 0
           }
         });
         return {
           "userId": user
         };
       } catch (e) {
         // IF ALREADY EXSIST THROW EXPECTION 403
         throw e;
       }
     }
    });
    // Client call method
    Meteor.call('register',{email: "vxxxxx@xxxx.com",password: "123456"}, function(error, result){
      if(result){
       console.log(result)
      }
      if(error){
       console.log(result)
      }
    });
```