# Meteor - Getting error when calling Accounts.onCreateUser

Tags: meteor

I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'onCreateUser'
at app/server/accounts.js:1:45
at app/server/accounts.js:6:3
```

When calling Accounts.onCreateUser in a file named accounts.js in my server folder

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) 
{
     return user;
});
```

Please can someone help explain what i'm doing wrong?

First week with Meteor! :)

Comment: Did you add any of the accounts packages? e.g. `meteor add accounts-password`

Comment: Yes accounts-password is added. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Did you add accounts-ui? To add Accounts and a set of login controls to an application, add the accounts-ui package and at least one login provider package: accounts-password, accounts-facebook, accounts-github, accounts-google, accounts-twitter, or accounts-weibo.

Comment: Yes accounts-ui is also there.

Comment: This answer is what i'm trying achieve http://stackoverflow.com/a/22181816/2687165

But if i use this code i get the above error. Does this call back need to be wrapped in any specific code for it to work?

Comment: Try `console.log` the contents of `Accounts` object just before calling `onCreateUser` method. What do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, embarrassing answer but thought i'd share in case any other newbies make the same mistake. I had created a collection with the name 'accounts' and this was causing a conflict and thus producing this error. I did not realise this was a reserved name in Meteor.

Answer (score 0):

Accounts depends the accounts-ui package,

A turn-key user interface for Meteor Accounts.

> To add Accounts and a set of login controls to an application, add the
>   accounts-ui package and at least one login provider package:
>   accounts-password, accounts-facebook, accounts-github,
>   accounts-google, accounts-twitter, or accounts-weibo.

http://docs.meteor.com/#accountsui

Comment: account-ui package is installed.

Comment: today I work with Meteor 0.9.2 and I have the same method and without problems

Comment: This is not true. Accounts doesn't depend on accounts-ui, and onCreateUser doesn't require accounts-ui either.