# How can I assign the first user in my Meteor app a specific role?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using [meteor-roles](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles) for permissions, and I'd like to add a particular role to the first user created. I know I can't use `addUsersToRoles` in the `onCreateUser` hook because it queries the database for the user ID but the user has not been added to the database yet.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13483188/800492) suggesting wrapping the `createUser` method, but that doesn't work for me. The server complains that `createUser` doesn't support callbacks yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can on the `OnCreateUser`, do something like this.

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
    //if there is not users on the database
    //we assign the First-User role
  if(Meteor.users.find().count() === 0){ 
     user.role = "First-User"
  }else{
     user.role = "normalUser"
   }
  return user;
});
```

Assuming you have the `First-user` role. like this.

```
Meteor.publish("First-User", function () {
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:this.userId});

  if (Roles.userIsInRole(user, ["First-User"])) {
    return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {emails: 1, profile: 1, roles: 1}});
  } 

  this.stop();
  return;
});
```

Remember you should call the `onCreateUser` at the top of the `createUsers` methods.

> Note that the Roles.addUsersToRoles call needs to come after
>   Accounts.createUser or Accounts.onCreate or else the roles package
>   won't be able to find the user record (since it hasn't been created
>   yet)

From [README](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles).

Hope this Works.

Comment: The `onCreateUser` hook works. Thanks! I don't understand the publication, though. What would that do for me in this case?

Comment: Nevermind. I get it now. That's the publication that delivers the user collection only to that user. Thanks!

Comment: @raddevon Awesome =D!