# Meteor: How to assign different roles to users during sign up process

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am using the meteor package [ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3](https://atmospherejs.com/ian/accounts-ui-bootstrap-3) for accounts and  [alanning:roles](https://atmospherejs.com/alanning/roles) for assigning roles.

On the sign up form I have two options one for **Doctor** and one for **Advisor**. I want to assign the selected option as a role to that user. Can someone let me know how to do this?

I have just started learning meteor and don't know much about its flow. I can assign roles to a user if I create the user manually like this:

```
var adminUser = Meteor.users.findOne({roles:{$in:["admin"]}});

if(!adminUser){

    adminUser = Accounts.createUser({
      email: "mohsin.rafi@mail.com",
      password: "admin",
      profile: { name: "admin" }
    });
    Roles.addUsersToRoles(adminUser, [ROLES.Admin]);
 }
```

But I want to assign a roll automatically as a user signs up and select one of the options and that option should be assigned as his role.

Comment: just a word about using profile. it seems like it's not a good idea: see "Dont use profile" in https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't need a hack for this. Instead of using `Accounts.onCreateUser` you can do it with the following hook on the `Meteor.users` collection. Something along the lines of the following should work:

```
Meteor.users.after.insert(function (userId, doc) {
    if (doc.profile.type === "doctor") {
        Roles.addUsersToRoles(doc._id, [ROLES.Doctor])
    } else if (doc.profile.type === "advisor") {
        Roles.addUsersToRoles(doc._id, [ROLES.Advisor])
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Works for me!

Comment: Maybe important to note that you need `meteor add matb33:collection-hooks` for this.

Answer (score 1):

To get around having to check on login every time it's possible to directly set the roles on the user object instead of using the Roles API.

A hack? Yep, you probably need to make sure the roles have already been added to roles... not sure if there's anything else yet.

```
if(Meteor.isServer){
  Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user){
    if(options.roles){
      _.set(user, 'roles.__global_roles__', ['coach', options.roles]);
    }
    return user;
  });
}
```

Note: _.set is a [lodash](https://atmospherejs.com/stevezhu/lodash) method not in underscorejs.

There's no pretty solution because:

1. There's no *server side* meteor callback post *complete* account creation.

   - In `onCreateUser` the user hasn't been added to the collection.
   - [`Accounts.createUser`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser)'s callback is currently only for use on the client.  A method could then be used from that callback but it would be insecure to rely on it.
2. The roles package seems to grab the user from the collection and in `onCreateUser` it's not there yet.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the [Accounts.onCreateUser](https://devdocs.io/meteor/index#accounts_oncreateuser) hook to manage that.

Please keep in mind the code below is fairly insecure and you would probably want to do more checking beforehand, otherwise anyone can assign themselves admin. (from docs):

> options may come from an untrusted client so make sure to validate any values you read from it.

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
  user.profile = options.profile || {};
  if (_.has(options, 'role')) {
    Roles.addUserToRoles(user._id, options.role);
  }
  return user;
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I tried your code but i am not getting 'role' in 'options'. I did console.log(options) and there was no roles field there and that might be reason it is not adding roles. On mongo when i do "db.users.find()" its also not showing roles field. But when i used "Accounts.onLogin" as i share my code below its working perfect. But i want it to work on "Accounts.onCreateUser".

Comment: `Roles.addUserToRoles` will not work in `onCreateUser` because the new user has not been added to the Meteor.users collection yet, even though there's a `user._id` that will be used to do so.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your response. I tried but it doesn't work for me.

I used [Accounts.onLogin](https://devdocs.io/meteor/index#accounts_onlogin) hook to to manage this. Below code works for me:

```
Accounts.onLogin(function (info) {
    var user = info.user;
    if(user.profile.type === "doctor"){
      Roles.addUsersToRoles(user, [ROLES.Doctor])
    }
    else 
      if(user.profile.type === "advisor"){
        Roles.addUsersToRoles(user, [ROLES.Advisor])
        }
    return user;
  });
```

Comment: This is pretty inefficient because you're doing at least one additional database query per login. What was the issue with @corvid's answer?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I tried @corvid's code but don't know why that didn't work for me. After running his code i was not getting any roles assigned to user.