# using matb33:collection-hooks in typescript

Tags: typescript, meteor-accounts, angular2-meteor

I am creating an Angular2-Meteor app, starting with the Socially tutorial. I am trying to implement user Roles using alanning:roles and matb33:collection-hooks. The solution would be similar to that proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30482814/meteor-how-to-assign-different-roles-to-users-during-sign-up-process/32468020#32468020). The only difference would be that Angular 2 requires typescript definitions for Roles and Collection-Hooks. 
I have found meteor-typescript-libs, which has a definition for Roles that seems to work. However, the only resource for collection-hooks I found was typed-meteor-collection-hooks. I tried referencing [index.d.ts](https://github.com/twastvedt/typed-meteor-collection-hooks/blob/master/index.d.ts) by copy/pasting the file into my project, but I still get the following error:

> server/imports/accounts.ts (30, 14): Property 'after' does not exist on type 'Collection < User >'.

At the following line:

```
Meteor.users.after.insert(function (userId, doc) {    
if (doc.profile.type === "basic") {
    Roles.addUsersToRoles(doc._id, [ROLES.Basic])
} else if (doc.profile.type === "admin") {
    Roles.addUsersToRoles(doc._id, [ROLES.Admin])
} else if (doc.profile.type === "manager") {
    Roles.addUsersToRoles(doc._id, [ROLES.Manager])
}});
```

I am new to typescript, and it's not clear to me how I should implement type definitions for Meteor Packages. Clearly, my approach is wrong. Does anyone have any experience with roles and collection-hooks in Meteor-Angular2?

UPDATE: It seems like the Meteor.users.after.insert() code is executing after inserting a user, despite the error. I am continuing development, but would appreciate a solution for removing the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried installing the typings from npm?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/meteor-collection-hooks

Don't forget to also add to your tsconfig "types" array like:

```
"types": [
  "@types/meteor-collection-hooks"
]
```

Comment: I can confirm this solution works once types are installed `npm install --save (or --save-dev) @types/meteor-collection-hooks`
It might be confusing for some as text editor might take some time to load it, eg, VS code in my case took at least 1 minute to propagate.