# Detect first time user for meteor app

Tags: android, ios, meteor

I am building an app with [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) and I am looking to create a first time user launch screen- something like an "About/Welcome" page. Essentially, something that would pull a one-time screen after launching the app for the first time and never appear again; if the user has already opened the app they would be directed to another page.

I am not using login credentials, so I need a different solution than checking to see if the user is logged in or not.

How would I go about configuring this? I have tried searching all over the web and can't seem to find a solution for this. Please note this is different from a "Launch Screen".

Comment: that's a bit hard because they can usually clear their browser cookies and local storage -- how accurate does it have to be?

Comment: It doesn't need to be super accurate. Just looking to have a one-time "tutorial" type of screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meteor: How do I show a page when a user signs up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956291/meteor-how-do-i-show-a-page-when-a-user-signs-up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to either use localstorage, or set a cookie.

I'd suggest trying localstorage first.  There are several packages on [atmosphere](https://atmospherejs.com/packages/localstorage) that should help,

Using the frozeman:storage package ([meteorpad example](http://meteorpad.com/pad/QhQYMdAzfeyNhvwCe/First%20Time%20Visitor)):

```
Template.body.helpers({
  beenHereBefore: function() {
    var beenHereBefore = LocalStore.get('BeenHereBefore',  {reactive: false});
    console.log(LocalStore.get('BeenHereBefore',  {reactive: false}));
    if (beenHereBefore !== true){
      LocalStore.set('BeenHereBefore', true, {reactive: false})

      console.log(LocalStore.get('BeenHereBefore',  {reactive: false}));
    }
    return beenHereBefore;
  },
});


<body>
  {{#unless beenHereBefore}}
    <h1> Welcome first time visitor! </h1>  
  {{else}}
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="logo"></div>
      <h1 class="title">Leaderboard</h1>
      <div class="subtitle">Select a scientist to give them points</div>
      {{> leaderboard}}
    </div>
  {{/unless}}
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just some simple JavaScript should do the trick:

```
if (Boolean(localStorage.getItem('visitedApp'))) {
  // user's been here before
} else {
  // do stuff for first time user
  localStorage.setItem('visitedApp', true);
}
```

Comment: Tried this and did not seem to work... :(
I added to a js file in client.

Comment: Well, it can't just be by itself in a file. It has to be in the right place in your code that checks if a user is new or not (that part is up to you since I can't see all your code, I wouldn't know where it goes).

Comment: This would probably go in the `onRendered` callback for your layout template.