# How to create a custom user authentication in Meteor?

Tags: authentication, meteor

I am trying to create the following authentication for an app:
User enters phone number and receives an SMS with a code generated in the server (the SMS is handled through an external service). If the user enters the right code he is logged in.
This means I must have two login stages: registering user with a phone and logging him in with the code, so this is what I think the client should look like:

```
Meteor.getSmsCode = function(phone, username, callback) {
  Accounts.callLoginMethod({
    methodName: 'getsmscode',
    methodArguments: [{
      getsmscode: true,
      phone: phone,
      username: username
    }],
    userCallback: callback
  });
};


Meteor.loginWithCode = function(phone, code, callback) {
  Accounts.callLoginMethod({
    methodName: 'login',
    methodArguments: [{
      hascode: true,
      phone: phone,
      code: code
    }],
    userCallback: callback
  });
};
```

But I am confused about the server side - there should be two methods:
the first should only register a user (and communicate with the SMS service) and second should log him in.

This is the server test code for now:

```
Meteor.users.insert({phone: '123456789', code: '123', username:'ilyo'});

Accounts.registerLoginHandler(function(loginRequest) {
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne({phone: loginRequest.phone});

  if(user.code !== loginRequest.code) {
    return null;
  }

  var stampedToken = Accounts._generateStampedLoginToken();
  var hashStampedToken = Accounts._hashStampedToken(stampedToken);

  Meteor.users.update(userId,
    {$push: {'services.resume.loginTokens': hashStampedToken}}
  );

  return {
    id: user._id,
    token: stampedToken.token
  };
});
```

And this is what happens when I try it:
[image]

- Why an I getting the `500`?
- Why doesn't the user have a `code` and `phone` fields?
- What method should I use for the `getSmsCode`?

Answer (score 0):

Meteor.createUser is described on [How can I create users server side in Meteor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629759/how-can-i-create-users-server-side-in-meteor)

Then, the Accounts.onCreateUser would contain business logic http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_oncreateuser

A more exact message for the 500 would be on the server-side stdout. Probably security.

Answer (score 0):

Your Login Handler must return an object as follows:

```
{ userId: user._id }
```

Sorry I don't elaborate in the whole problem, I don't agree on your full approach but looks you are in the right path to get the feature you need.

Also, this question is one year old, now there are a few packages at atmosphere that address this kind of authentication =)